# RemixD not connecting to folder

Tags: node.js, ethereum, remix

When I run the following I get the errors below - is there anything I can do to solve this? tried on Mac OS and Linux with the same issue

remixd -s /home/garrett/ --remix-ide http://remix.ethereum.org/

[WARN] You may now only use IDE at http://remix.ethereum.org/ to connect to that instance
[WARN] Any application that runs on your computer can potentially read from and write to all files in the directory.
[WARN] Symbolic links are not forwarded to Remix IDE

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/remixd/lib/bin/remixd.js:35 throw new Error(error);

Error: TypeError: Class constructor PluginClient cannot be invoked without 'new'
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/remixd/lib/bin/remixd.js:35:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:609:3
```

Comment: You'll get an answer over at: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Works fine on macOS Catalina

1. npm cache clean -f;
2. sudo npm i remixd@0.2.2-alpha.0 -g --unsafe-perm;
3. remixd -s /home/garrett/ --remix-ide http://remix.ethereum.org/;